# simple.json in java fail to print JsonObject

Tags: java, json

Im using the following Json file and JavaCode. I would like to be able parse the JSON file but fail to do so. Im working with JSON for the first time.

```
[
   {
       "1": "5.645751953125E-3",
       "2": "5.79833984375E-3",
       "3": "4.57763671875E-3",
       "fp": "t1"
   },
   {
       "1": "0.575408935546875",
       "2": "0.3570556640625",
       "3": "0.2325439453125",
       "fp": "t2"
    },
    {
       "fp": ""
    }
 ]
```

```html
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SCR {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try
        {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\2003log.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("fp");
            System.out.println(name);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The errormessage is: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

I can't resolve this. Greateful for help.

Comment: Your problem is pretty clear: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Try converting to JSONArray instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Object is an array, so you should cast it to `JSONArray` not to  `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

Your obj is an JSONArray containing multiple JSONObjects so you can not cast it to JSONObject.

You should cast it to JSONArray and then you can pull out the objects one by one